# How do we authenticate a third-party external server against our Firebase server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We have a third-party which would like to make an API call to our server which is authenticated w/ Firebase.

This API endpoint will be used to generate credits ($), and we'd also like to avoid giving this third-party complete administrative privileges (database, cloud functions, etc).

Giving them the `service-account.json` would give them full administrative privileges.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Options I know of:

- **Admin SDK installed on Third-Party** -> Not a viable/great option without having a way to limit functionality. We cannot ensure that they implement any user permissions if they do this.
- **Use WebSDK** (javascript) and authenticate as if they were a user (email, password) -> Seems a bit hacky
- [Create Custom Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) -> Expires every hour, is an option

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't quite understand your requirement, but https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens might be what you need.